# MDX query to calculate inventory

Tags: ssas, mdx, business-intelligence, ssas-2008

The fact table is quite simple :

```
Date       Product Area
========== ======= ====
2010-01-01 P1      A
2010-01-01 P2      B
2010-01-02 P1      B
...
```

There is a large number of areas that we can't know in advance

The desired result is :

```
Date       A  B  ...
========== == == ==
2010-01-01 1  1  ...
2010-01-02 0  2  ...
...
```

I'm looking for a query to do this job.

Comment: Do you already have this loaded in SSAS? What are your facts and dimensions called? Is the fact a snapshot table? Do you have a measure in it that is something like a last nonempty on product?

Comment: I've created similar objets in SSAS but I expose here the main problem, no matter tables and dimensions name. If a dimension or a calculate member is needed, we can assume that it exists. The fact table I give here said that such a date , such a product is present at such a place. There are only this 2 measures in the fact table (product and area), no "last nonempty" but we can create a calculate member if it is needed.

Answer (score 1):

I would write a query:

```
WITH MEMBER X AS
COUNT([DimProduct].[Product].[Product])
SELECT
{[DimProduct].[Product area].[product area]} ON COLUMNS,
[Dim date].[date].[date]
ON ROWS
FROM [Cube name]
WHERE X
```

Jiri

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT

[Dim product area].[Prod area].children ON 0,

[Dim periods].[Dates].children ON 1

FROM [cubename]
```

Comment: Thank you for your try, but all values are (null). Perhaps I have to do something special with this 2 dimensions ?

Comment: It's hard to write the query wirhout knowing the cube structure.

Comment: if all (or a lot of) values are null, a NON EMPTY clause may be enough to fix it.

Comment: @sen77 How is this ever going to work? When a measure is not specified, the default member in `measures` dimension will be taken into consideration. Its very much required to specify the measure.

Comment: @SouravA Given conditions doesn't tell us about measures. My assumption was the cube has just one measure because "_The fact table is quite simple_"